# Differenze di uso tra "fai come credi" e "fai come ti pare"

Tags: word-usage, verbs, difference

In principio, "parere" può avere il significato di "credere". Ecco una delle accezioni data dal [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/parere2):

> **2. a.** Ritenere, credere, giudicare (col soggetto logico nel dativo: *mi pare*, *ti pare*, ecc.)

Tuttavia, ho l'impressione che ci sia qualche
piccola differenza tra l'uso di queste due frasi:

> Fai come credi

e

> Fai / fa' come ti pare.

Capisco che il loro senso dipenda dal tono in cui vengano pronunciate, ma ho la sensazione che la prima si possa usare spesso con un tono più neutro, mentre la seconda sia solita dirsi quando si è arrabbiati con l'interlocutore; ma potrei essere completamente sbagliata ed è questa la ragione per cui pongo questa domanda. È veramente così? E, se non è così, esiste qualche differenza di uso tra queste due frasi?

Comment: No, non è così, o lo è pochissimo. Nota a margine: quandi?

Comment: Non so da dove arrivi la tua"sensazione", ma per un madrelingua le due espressioni sono perfettamente equivalenti.

Comment: Interessante domanda. Effettivamente le due espressioni “suonano” in modo lievemente diverso nel verso che dici, ma per dare una risposta oggettiva, al di là dell'orecchio del singolo parlante, bisognerebbe per esempio trovare campioni di testi narrativi o presi dal parlato reale, e vedere i contesti in cui le si usa.

Comment: Mmm... Hai ragione, @DaG: poter fare questo sarebbe davvero interessante.

Comment: @DaG Potresti spiegare perché "suonano in modo lievemente diverso"?

Comment: È di sicuro una mia opinione personale, ma  "fa' come ti pare" mi è sempre suonato leggermente più sgarbato. Ripeto, opinione personale / abitudine.
Altre espressioni analoghe: "Fai come vuoi"; "Fai (pure) di testa tua".

Comment: Interessante, @RiccardoDeContardi. E dicendo "fa' pure come ti pare" si riesce ancora di più a trasmettere il tono "arrabbiato".

Comment: Ripensandoci, penso che questa domanda ponga  principalmente una POB issue.

Comment: Perché sarebbe così, @Gio? E non capisco neanche perché hai cancellato la tua risposta: quello che hai citato del Treccani mi sembra davvero relevante per la domanda.

Comment: @Gio: Secondo me, quello che dice il Treccani o questo tipo di pubblicazioni non sono cose da prendersi come un'"opinion based" qualsiasi.

Comment: In [questa pubblicazione di Gregorio Costa](https://books.google.es/books?id=uiZcAAAAMAAJ&q=%22faccia+come+le+pare%22&dq=%22faccia+come+le+pare%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjg-deCorXoAhVlkFwKHfdnAJUQ6AEwCXoECAIQAQ), edita nella *Nuova collana di linguistica* da Giardini editori, ho trovato: «[...], dal contesto, dal tono, dall'ironia con cui eventualmente vengono dette: *Faccia come crede*, che è meno familiare e più sostenuto di *Faccia come le pare*, corrisponderà meglio a *Faites comme bon vous semble*. Ed in queste due frasi si colgono già le, sia pur minime, divergenze nelle scelte lessicali»